# MVC C# Carousel Image

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

i have been trying to create a carousel image on my MVC application. The below snippet from W3 was just used as an example. The result was the images displayed ont he webpage one below eachother. Do i need to do anything else on the MVC application to resolve this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/newyork.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The example on the W3 site uses jQuery/Bootstrap.  If you haven't loaded those scripts, it won't work.  Copy and run all the code from their [TryIt Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h) section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same requirement sometime ago and I used below code, look if it works for you.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    @{
        var first = true;
    }
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Images)
    {
        <div class="carousel-item @(first?Html.Raw("active"):Html.Raw(""))">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="@item.Image" alt="@item.Name">
        </div>
        first = false;
    }
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
                                 data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
                                 data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Mate!  I ended up using a different work around but that is what i was looking for!

Comment: Good to hear! would you mind voting the answer if you think it is worth?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this.I hope your problem is solved

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">  
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">  
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>  
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>  
            <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>  
        </ul>           
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">  
            @{int i = 0;}  
            @foreach (var item in Model)  
            {  
                i++;  
                var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";  
                <div class="carousel-item @active">  
                    <img src="@Url.Content(@item.FilePath)" alt="">  
                </div>  
            }  
        </div>  
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">  
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>  
        </a>  
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">  
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>  
        </a>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.